# Can I swap CSS classes for a particluar Set of element through JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've TWO LIs as written below:-

```
<li name="luxury" class="cars luxury>                                           
    <div id="featured_lux" name="featured" class="carImg_lux col2_lux ">
        My Luxury Car<img border="0" class="car-image_lux" src="/images/toycar_luxury.gif">
    </div>

    <div class="brandName_lux col2_lux">
        <h2 class="showBig_lux">
            Ferrari or Ford Mustang
        </h2> 

    </div>          

</li>
```

AND this

```
<li name="normal" class="cars normal>
        <div id="featured_normal" name="normal" class="carImg_normal col2_normal ">
            My Normal Car<img border="0" class="car-image_lux" src="/images/toycar_normal.gif">
        </div>

        <div class="brandName_normal col2_normal">
            <h2 class="showBig_normal">
                Alto or Innova
            </h2> 

        </div>          

    </li>
```

Both looks similar. Difference is their CSS class and content.

Can I swap CSS classes for both set of elements through Jquery ? 
For example. Normal Car Section should be applied with Luxury CSS and viceversa.

I can achieve it by using addClass() and removeClass() in jQuery. 
Is there any direct approach with minimal line of code effort?

And above approach should run by default based on some condition. ( No Click or Hover. )

I don't want to use any external Library( iF EXIST ).

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can use JQuery, now go try it ;)

Comment: If you can achieve it using addClass() and removeClass(), maybe it's enough?

Comment: No.. through addCSS and removeCss, i am creating huge lines of code in my script. Approx 15-18 lines to remove existing and adding new CSS. But I just want to achieve it with minimal lines of code ( Refined Code )

Comment: What do you mean by 'run by default based on some condition'? Is it call to the swap class function inside an if?

Comment: Yes.. if condition is working..addClass, removeClass, toggleClass also. But I have huge elements in one LI and same Huge elements in other LI with different CSS names. So suppost there are 20 different CSS in both LIs, then I atleast have to write toggleClass for 20 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass`.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.swap').click(function() {
        $('.a, .b').toggleClass('a b');
    });
});
```

```css
.a { background: red; }
.b { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">#</div>
<div class="b">#</div>
<input type="button" class="swap" value="Swap Classes" />
```

You can create a function to pass classes to it to swap. Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
    swapClasses('red', 'blue');
    function swapClasses(a, b) {
        $('.' + a + ', ' + '.' + b).toggleClass(a + ' ' + b);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
}
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">RED</div>
<div class="blue">BLUE</div>
```

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z2ogcs3x/

Comment: I dont have any click or hover function.On Page load,  Based on some condition, it should swap CSS from one to another. That's it.

Comment: Sure, I added the button for demonstration. You should be able to apply my example to whatever page load condition you have.

Comment: Thanx for help. But ToggleClass again I have to write for 6-7 times as above mentioned sample contains 6 CSS Classes. AM I RGHT ? :(

Comment: Nothing is going to magically program this for you. `toggleClass` is about is high level as you're going to get for swapping classes between elements.

Comment: Hey Thanks.. Then I have to stay with toggleClass if there is no other way. I would follow it.   But just to tell, Above mentioned is sample code. In One Li.. I have different new Div elements which also has CSS classes. So Suppose, I have 20 CSS for  a Large LI and same new 20 CSS for another Larger LI then in case, I atleast have to write toggleClass 20 times. I would follow or have to follow this.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. From your question it seemed like you were simply looking for a faster way to swap classes than to use `addClass` and `removeClass`, but now it seems like you need a function to swap classes of elements passed to it. Is that right?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional example of a function you can use to swap two classes.

Comment: Yeah.. U understood right. But i did understande there is not other way in jQuery i can achieve it through few lines. I will follow your approach. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use vanilla code, you can use [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), a site with jQuery ways of doing stuff and their vanilla implementations.

For example:

jQuery code:

```
$(el).addClass(className);
```

Vanilla code:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.add(className);
else
  el.className += ' ' + className;
```

Comment: I want to achive through Jquery. Business Requirements :(